# How can I make an http request in the service worker chrome extension?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, http, google-chrome-extension, manifest

i am trying to develope a chrome extension ,now background scripts are replaced by service workers in manifest v3, How can I make an http request in the service worker?

Comment: Use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 5):

Use this in your service worker:

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

Don't forget to set proper permissions in the manifest file:

```
  "host_permissions": [
    "http://example.com/"
  ],
```